# Динамическое добавление фрагмента в контейнер на другом фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, android-data-binding

С помощью PagerView создаю несколько фрагментов со схожим содержимым (список объектов). Пример:

Схожая часть: содержат поле типа vehicle

`data class Vehicle(// ..список полей)`

Различающаяся часть: (для примера)

`data class Lorry(val idVehicle: Int,val cargoWeight: Int)`

Средств передвижения несколько типов.
В зависимости от того, какой тип средства передвижения отображаю, показываю дополнительные поля (например, поле cargoWeight) как фрагмент. По умолчанию имею контейнер типа SpecificFragment, фрагменты с дополнительной информацией по средству передвижения расширяют этот класс, например:

`class LorryCharacteristicsFragment: SpecificFragment(){..}`

Вопрос: как заполнять контейнер динамически? При способе, который использую сейчас, контейнет заполняется на первой вкладке pagerView (то есть, туда наслаиваются все фрагменты, которые добавляю).
Необходимо как-то получать id контейнера, но я не знаю как (использую binding).
Что есть сейчас:

```
    fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
        ?.setReorderingAllowed(true)
        ?.add(R.id.specific_vehic_info_container, selectTypeFragment(vehicle = vehicle)!!)
        ?.commit()
```

Не знаю как получить id контейнера именно на этой вкладке viewPager

Answer (score 0):

Ларчик открывался просто.
Во-первых, при использовании databinding мы не можем обратиться к фрагменту как binding.fragment, тк фрагмент не является View.
Фрагмент:

```
<fragment
                android:id="@+id/specific_vehic_container"
                android:name="com.olzumzum.race_app.ui.SpecificFragment"
                android:tag="fragment_specific_vehic_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
```

Обращение:

```
val specFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment_specific_vehic_container")
```

Чтобы поместить новый фрагмент в контейнер, находящийся в другом фрагменте, нужно использовать не fragmentManager, а childFragmentManager:

```
childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
            .add(specFragment?.id!!, selectTypeFragment(vehicle = vehicle)!!)
            .commit()
```